# How to install package spatie pdf to img in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I already install GhostScript and imagick and it's working well in php artisan, now when i install this package [Spatie/pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) it does not have service provider and alias in installation steps. Can you guys help me how to install this package and make it work?

**Not Working:**
[image: Not Work]

**Working in php artisan:**
[image]

**I also try this one and doesn't work:**

```
$pdf = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf('public/test/test.pdf');
$pdf = new \Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf('public/test/test.pdf');
```

**Here's my composer:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try again with:

```
$pdf = new \Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf('public/test/test.pdf');
```

Previous error was caused because of wrong namespace. It's better to add `Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf` to use section at the top of document and then in code just write `$pdf = new Pdf('path/to/pdf');`

Comment: this one works, $pdf = new \Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf('test/naks.pdf'); because it does not throw an exception. why does my application stop responding and respond "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET", is laravel cost this? or does my ghostscript cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You first run this command on CMD :

```
composer require spatie/pdf-to-image
```

After add this lines in your controller

```
use Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf;


$pdf = new Pdf($pathToPdf);
$pdf->saveImage($pathToWhereImageShouldBeStored);
```